# flutter run behind proxy fails to download gradle dependency despite setting proxy explicity

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter is supposed to use proxy env vars when fetching dependencies but it fails to do so.

```sh
> $env:http_proxy="127.0.0.1:8090"
> $env:https_proxy="127.0.0.1:8090"
> $env:NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1"

> flutter create app
> cd app
> flutter run

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

I know using a VPN is an option too. But I prefer to use a proxy.
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind proxy you have to set proxy for **gradle** explicitly **AGAIN** which means **gradle** doesn't respect env vars that is kind of annoying. anyway here you go.

### create a `gradle.properties` file under `.gradle` directory in your home folder.

```sh
code ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

### Paste the following into it

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost={ProxyIP}
systemProp.http.proxyPort={ProxyPort}
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost={ProxyIP}
systemProp.https.proxyPort={ProxyPort}
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
```

In my case `maven.org` and `jitpack.io` domains can be browsed directly.

And don't forget to run `flutter clean` before `flutter run`. To see what's going on run `flutter run -v`